# helm generate serviceaccount

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have values.yaml with more apps

```
app1:
  replicas:1
  annotations:
    example: "one"
  labels:
    app: "example"
app2:
  replicas:1
  annotations:
    example: "twoo"
  labels:
    app: "example2"
app3:
  replicas:1
  annotations: {}
  labels: {}
```

And my serviceaccount.yaml

```
{{- range $key, $value := .Values }}
  {{- if (eq $key "app1") }}
  {{- if or (eq $key "app1") (eq $key "app2") }}
    {{- $value := .Values | get $name }}
{{- if $value }}
{{- $d := $value | fromYaml }}
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ServiceAccount
    metadata:
      name: {{ if .resourceNameOverride }}{{ .resourceNameOverride }}{{ else }}'{{ $key }}'{{ end }}
      labels:
              {{- mergeOverwrite $d .labels | toYaml | nindent 4 }}
      annotations:
              {{- include "test.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
        {{- mergeOverwrite $d .labels | toYaml | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

The goal is to create one template that will generate serviceaccount
Code return error  wrong type for value; expected map[string]interface {}; got string
How to fix?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of typing errors in this setup (and one top-level logic I'd change).

For now let's simplify the values to

```yaml
# simplified values.yaml
app1:
  labels:
    app: "example"
```

First, when you try to extract the value from `.Values`

```
{{- range $key, $value := .Values }}
{{- $value := .Values | get $name }}
{{- if $value }}
{{- $d := $value | fromYaml }}
```

`$value` is already a dictionary as represented in the values file.  You only need `fromYaml` if you have a text block that you need to parse, but you're not in this case.  So you don't need `fromYaml` here.  (You also don't need the `get` call, since you already have the value from the assignment in the `range` loop, but let's keep it for now.)

The other place you'll hit a type problem is trying to set the labels

```yaml
labels:
  {{- mergeOverwrite $d .labels | toYaml | nindent 4 }}
```

This call, read in isolation, expects a dictionary in the variable `$d`; it also expects the special variable `.` to be a dictionary, and reads the `labels` field from it, also expecting a dictionary; and it overwrites the values in `$d` with the values from `.labels`.

I don't think this is what you mean, though.  If `$d` is the per-account dictionary, you don't want to modify it at all, you just want to extract the labels dictionary from it.  `$d.labels` is the template syntax for this reference.

Also remember that YAML is extremely whitespace-sensitive and Helm won't try to reformat your file beyond the template whitespace controls.  I'd align all of the actual YAML content starting at the left-hand column and double-check the `indent` values.

I mentioned a top-level change up front.  Rather than iterating through `values` and seeing if the keys match, I might write out a list of keys I expect and retrieve them.  This can be helpful for predictability and it's probably a little easier to read and write.

Putting this all together, I'd get:

```yaml
{{- range $key := list "app1" "app2" "app3" }}
{{- with $value := index .Values $key }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: {{ with $value.resourceNameOverride }}{{ . }}{{ else }}{{ $key }}{{ end }}
  labels:
{{ include "test.labels" $ | indent 4 }}
{{ $value.labels | toYaml | indent 4 }}
{{- with $value.annotations }}
  annotations:
{{ . | toYaml | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```